# How to handle nearest element based upon select option in angular 5?

Tags: html, angular

I have to **access nearest element** of **dropdown**.
Below html have multiple **dropdown** and **input** boxes, so while select others in dropdown i have to enable and disable the nearest input box of the block.

```
<div class="form-block" *ngFor="let applicant of consumerData;">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="label__select-form--hidden">Type</label>                    
  <div class="select-dropdown">
    <select class="select-menu" (change)="onTypeChange($event.target.value)">
            <option value="medical">Major Medical</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>   

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="othersLabel">Others</label>
     <div class="form-textbox">
       <input class="form-control" id="othersLabel" name="othersLabel">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

For quick review, i have updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wucaru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Thanks in advance for quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Declare Template Variable in your Select Button then use the template variable to disable the input button i have edited the code try this way

```
<div class="form-block" *ngFor="let applicant of consumerData;">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="label__select-form--hidden">Type</label>                    
  <div class="select-dropdown">
    <select class="select-menu" #v (change)="onTypeChange($event.target.value)">
            <option value="medical">Major Medical</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>   

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="othersLabel">Others</label>
     <div class="form-textbox">
       <input class="form-control" id="othersLabel" name="othersLabel" [disabled]="v.value=='Others'">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yuwyf

Comment: Thank you so much buddy its working. Please share any simple tutorial link for **template variable**.

Comment: Check this bro https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-template-reference-variable-example